# undefined local variable or method `resource_class' for #<PostsController:0xd034f28>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

ruby 2.3.3 & rails 5.2

I am getting this error

> undefined local variable or method `resource_class' for # PostsController:0xd034f28>

Please here is my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, If: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end     
end
```

my post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit        
    end

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :link, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: `If: :devise_controller?` should be `if: :devise_controller?`, with small i in if

Comment: @Vasilisa  hahaaahaa!  worked. thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?`

Comment: This answer was auto-flagged because it's short. But it's still an answer, not a link or a comment.